# Save user's id in the database, when submitting the form in django

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a form that user can add his feed URL and then see the articles of the feeds he has submitted before. 
How can I change my code in order to save the owner of the feed (the user that submitted it to the site)?

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Feed(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    url = models.URLField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title

class Article(models.Model):
    feed = models.ForeignKey(Feed)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    url = models.URLField()
    description = models.TextField()
    publication_date = models.DateTimeField()

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title
```

**views.py:**

```
from .models import Article, Feed
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import FeedForm

def new_feed(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = FeedForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        feed = form.save(commit=False)

        existingFeed = Feed.objects.filter(url=feed.url)
        if len(existingFeed)==0:
            feedData = feedparser.parse(feed.url)

            feed.title = feedData.feed.title
            feed.save()

            for entry in feedData.entries:
                article = Article()
                article.title = entry.title
                article.url = entry.link
                article.description = entry.description

                d = datetime.datetime(*(entry.published_parsed[0:6]))
                dateString = d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

                article.publication_date = dateString
                article.feed = feed
                article.save()

        return redirect(feeds_list)
else:
    form = FeedForm()
return render(request, 'news/new_feed.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Feed

class FeedForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Feed
        fields = ('url',)
```

After adding a new feed, using this form:
(The feed, hasn't any owner (user))
[image: The feed, hasn't any owner (user)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
feed.save()
feed.user.add(*[request.user]) #try request.user.id also
```

Comment: Now I got this error: `'User' object is not iterable` @itzmeontv

Comment: now `unhashable type: 'list'` error for `feed.user.add([request.user])`

Comment: try this also `feed.user.add(*[request.user])`